Nginx Proxymanager "map" directive is not allowed
I'm in the process of deploying my Django project right now, I have a server on digital ocean and I'm setting up and nginx proxy manager. I have added the SSL certificate for Portainer, and when I add it for the main containers, I get an internal error:
nginx: [emerg] "map" directive is not allowed here in /data/nginx/proxy_host/2.conf:32
This is my file 2.conf:
map $scheme $hsts_header {
    https   "max-age=63072000; preload";
}

server {
  set $forward_scheme http;
  set $server         "api";
  set $port           1998;

  listen 80;
listen [::]:80;

  server_name fifumain.site www.fifumain.site;

  # Block Exploits
  include conf.d/include/block-exploits.conf;

  access_log /data/logs/proxy-host-2_access.log proxy;
  error_log /data/logs/proxy-host-2_error.log warn;

  map $scheme $hsts_header {
    https   "max-age=63072000; preload";
}

  location /api/v1/ {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass       http://api:1998;


  # Block Exploits
  include conf.d/include/block-exploits.conf;

  }

  map $scheme $hsts_header {
    https   "max-age=63072000; preload";
}

  location /supersecretadmin {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass       http://api:1998;

  # Block Exploits
  include conf.d/include/block-exploits.conf;
  }

  map $scheme $hsts_header {
    https   "max-age=63072000; preload";
}

  location / {
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Scheme $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto  $scheme;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For    $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP          $remote_addr;
    proxy_pass       http://api:1998;

  # Block Exploits
  include conf.d/include/block-exploits.conf;
  }

  # Custom
  include /data/nginx/custom/server_proxy[.]conf;
}

Based on the documentation, I understand that these maps do not belong inside the server block, but in the http block, but there are two problems - I do not have this block, and if I delete all the maps except the first one, and then restart the container, they still reappear in this config file, and I can not create SSL certificates, and to use in general further nginx proxy manager.

Find the reason why they reappear inside the file. Definitely not a nginx's problem.

Your configuration has four instances of map $scheme directives. One is outside server block and rest are in server blocks.
Remove the ones in the server blocks.
